# Nginx: Using the try_files Directive to create a pretty URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I want anything inside the /widget/ folder IE:

```
www.site.com/widget/1/2/3
```

rewritten as

```
www.site.com/index.php?type=widget&a=1&b=2&c=3
```

using the try_files directive

any files outside of the widget folder IE:

```
www.site.com/cool_stuff.php
```

should be unaffected by this rewrite

After many failed attempts I'm unable to get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try_files` receives a list of arguments representing which files Nginx should pass the request on to. For example: `try_files $uri $uri/ index.php =404` informs Nginx that it should try to match a request against `$uri` (the requested path as a file name, post-rewrites) `$uri/` (the requested path as a directory, post-rewrites), then to try `index.php`, and if all else fails, return an HTTP 404 Not Found error code. Another example: to map every request to a index.php, regardless of it's URI, use `try_files index.php =404;`.

In this case, I don't think try_files is the best directive for your requirements. Instead, consider using rewrite rules to transform `/widget/1/2/3` into `/index.php?type=widget&a=1&b=2&c=3`